# Kill(filepath) throws exception when no file exists

Tags: vb.net, file, exception, kill

`Kill(filePath)` throws an exception when no file exists, but only when I install the compiled app in a separate XP environment.

When I run the app out of the VS2005 IDE it *doesn't* throw an exception, which is the behaviour I would prefer.

Why is this function operating differently across the two environments?

Comment: Why do you use `Kill` (and not `File.Delete`) and why dont you simply check IF the file exists before you try do do something with it?

Comment: I ask mainly out of curiosity because I want to know why the function is behaving differently in two different environments.

Comment: You might want to specify what kind of exception is `an exception`. MOST times, when it runs on the developer machine but not on the target machine, it's a problem of access rights. And of course: The file could exist on YOUR machine, but not on some other!